# Count Distinct with Subquery throws error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an sql query where I count receipts. I want to count a) all receipts, b) receipts where the related customer has registered in the same year/month, c) receipts where the related customer has visited the store at least 4 times. The query is grouped over year and month. I hope it is comprehensible.

```
SELECT  t.Year, t.Month, 
COUNT(DISTINCT fs.Receipt) AS NumberOfGuests, //fs.Receipt is Receipt Number
COUNT(DISTINCT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Year AND MONTH(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Month
        THEN fs.Receipt END)) AS NumberOfNewGuests,
COUNT(DISTINCT 
    (CASE WHEN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fs_sub.Receipt)
            FROM Dimension_Time AS t_sub 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Fact_Sales AS fs_sub ON t_sub.ID = fs_sub.Time AND fs_sub.Store = @storeID
            WHERE t_sub.Time = t.Time AND fs_sub.CustomerID = fs.CustomerID
        ) > 3
    THEN fs.Receipt END)) AS NumberOfRegularGuests
FROM Dimension_Time AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Fact_Sales AS fs ON t.ID = fs.Time AND fs.Store = @storeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dimension_Customer AS c ON fs.Customer = c.ID
WHERE     (t.Time >= DATEFROMPARTS(2021 - 1, 5, 1)) AND (t.Time <= EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 1)))
GROUP BY t.Month, t.Year
ORDER BY t.Year, t.Month
```

NumberOfGuests and NumberOfNewGuests works fine, but with NumberOfRegularGuests, I get an error:
**Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.**
Is it possible to build the query another way to avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the subquery into an `APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT  t.Year, t.Month, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT fs.Receipt) AS NumberOfGuests, //fs.Receipt is Receipt Number
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
      (CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Year AND MONTH(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Month
        THEN fs.Receipt END)) AS NumberOfNewGuests,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
      (CASE WHEN t2.countReceipts > 3 THEN fs.Receipt END)
      ) AS NumberOfRegularGuests
FROM Dimension_Time AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Fact_Sales AS fs ON t.ID = fs.Time AND fs.Store = @storeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dimension_Customer AS c ON fs.Customer = c.ID
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fs_sub.Receipt) AS countReceipts
            FROM Dimension_Time AS t_sub 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Fact_Sales AS fs_sub ON t_sub.ID = fs_sub.Time AND fs_sub.Store = @storeID
            WHERE t_sub.Time = t.Time AND fs_sub.CustomerID = fs.CustomerID
        ) t2
WHERE     (t.Time >= DATEFROMPARTS(2021 - 1, 5, 1)) AND (t.Time <= EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 1)))
GROUP BY t.Month, t.Year
ORDER BY t.Year, t.Month;
```

But a subquery of this type is usually pretty inefficient (although this can depend on indexing as well as cardinalities ie how much of `Fact_Sales` is actually being used after filtering on dates). It can be replace by a windowed aggregate.

```sql
SELECT  t.Year, t.Month, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT fs.Receipt) AS NumberOfGuests, //fs.Receipt is Receipt Number
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
      (CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Year AND MONTH(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Month
        THEN fs.Receipt END)) AS NumberOfNewGuests,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
      (CASE WHEN fs.countReceipts > 3 THEN fs.Receipt END)
      ) AS NumberOfRegularGuests
FROM Dimension_Time AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fs.CustomerID) AS countReceipts
    FROM Fact_Sales
) AS fs ON t.ID = fs.Time AND fs.Store = @storeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dimension_Customer AS c ON fs.Customer = c.ID
WHERE     (t.Time >= DATEFROMPARTS(2021 - 1, 5, 1)) AND (t.Time <= EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 1)))
GROUP BY t.Month, t.Year
ORDER BY t.Year, t.Month;
```

It's unclear why you have `COUNT(DISTINCT` as opposed to just `COUNT`, this is usually an indication of a poorly thought-out join.

If it is indeed the case that there are multiple `Fact_Sales` with the same `Receipt` then you would need to change the window aggregate, as you cannot use `COUNT(DISTINCT...) OVER...`

```sql
SELECT  t.Year, t.Month, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT fs.Receipt) AS NumberOfGuests, //fs.Receipt is Receipt Number
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
      (CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Year AND MONTH(c.RegistrationDate) = t.Month
        THEN fs.Receipt END)) AS NumberOfNewGuests,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
      (CASE WHEN fs.countReceipts > 3 THEN fs.Receipt END)
      ) AS NumberOfRegularGuests
FROM Dimension_Time AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY fs.CustomerID) AS countReceipts
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fs.CustomerID ORDER BY fs.Receipt) AS rn
        FROM Fact_Sales
    ) AS fs
) AS fs ON t.ID = fs.Time AND fs.Store = @storeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dimension_Customer AS c ON fs.Customer = c.ID
WHERE     (t.Time >= DATEFROMPARTS(2021 - 1, 5, 1)) AND (t.Time <= EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 1)))
GROUP BY t.Month, t.Year
ORDER BY t.Year, t.Month;
```

Comment: It was a great help, but you're right, performance is an issue with APPLY. In the end I used LEFT JOIN in combination with cte's for a much faster query.